# Does object destructing uses more memory if i use it in most of the components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object-destructuring, react-functional-component

Let's say i have this component,

```
export default function Xyz(props) {
   ...
}

If i use object destructing,

export default function Xyz({x, y, z}) {
   ...
}
```

I want know that if i use the destructing method for every method for every function component and also in render method of traditional component, will it uses is more memory or will it take little load because of the so many consts or lets variable in application.

is there any tool or something so can measure this thing ? or someone just did that already ? i would like to understand how dose it works actually.

Comment: I think the reverse is true, but it's probably completely negligible, and you should be using Babel anyway, so it shouldn't matter even then

Comment: I smell overthinking and leading to premature optimization,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @CertainPerformace mentioned, I think that it should not matter anyway.
Because, we will be transpiling it to es5/3 either way using babel/webpack/typescript as it will be used inside the browser.

js

```
// this becomes
export default function Xyz({x, y, z}) {
    // ...
}
// this
export default function Xyz(options) {
    var x = options.x;
    var y = options.y;
    var z = options.z;
    // All logic 
}
```

So, I guess it won't matter as long as the code is designed to run in the browser.
Hope it helps :)